# Derivatives of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

In the [matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274), Eq. 59, the formula:
$$
\partial_x Y^{-1}=-Y^{-1}(\partial_x Y) Y^{-1}
$$
is provided without proof.

How to prove this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity
$$
YY^{-1}=I
$$
implies that (chain rule)
$$
\partial_x YY^{-1} + Y\partial_x Y^{-1}=0,
$$
so that 
$$ \partial_x Y^{-1} = -Y^{-1}\partial_x YY^{-1}. $$